# I'm having trouble downloading wildfly dependencies

Tags: java, wildfly

Good morning guys, i have a problem to download dependencys for quickstart/hello-world , for wildfly.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.wildfly.quickstarts</groupId>
    <artifactId>quickstart-parent</artifactId>
    <!--
    Maintain separation between the artifact id and the version to help prevent
    merge conflicts between commits changing the GA and those changing the V.
    -->
    <version>19.0.0.Beta1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>
<artifactId>helloworld</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>Quickstart: helloworld</name>
<description>Helloworld</description>

<licenses>
    <license>
        <name>Apache License, Version 2.0</name>
        <distribution>repo</distribution>
        <url>http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html</url>
    </license>
</licenses>

<dependencies>

    <!-- Import the CDI API, we use provided scope as the API is included in WildFly -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.enterprise</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.enterprise.cdi-api</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Import the Common Annotations API (JSR-250), we use provided scope
        as the API is included in WildFly -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.annotation</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-annotations-api_1.3_spec</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Import the Servlet API, we use provided scope as the API is included in WildFly -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-servlet-api_4.0_spec</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

After build eclipse list erros:

> [ERROR] Non-resolvable import POM: Could not transfer artifact org.wildfly.bom:wildfly-jakartaee8- 
>       with-tools:pom:19.0.0.Beta1-SNAPSHOT from/to centralnexus 
>       (https://fabricaportal.accenture.com/nexus/repository/OI_Central/): Access denied to 
>       https://fabricaportal.accenture.com/nexus/repository/OI_Central/org/wildfly/bom/wildfly-jakartaee8- 
>       with-tools/19.0.0.Beta1-SNAPSHOT/wildfly-jakartaee8-with-tools-19.0.0.Beta1-SNAPSHOT.pom. Error code 
>       401, Unauthorized @ org.wildfly.quickstarts:quickstart-parent:19.0.0.Beta1-SNAPSHOT, 
>       C:\Users\victor.hugo.b.silva\Desktop\quickstart\pom.xml, line 101, column 25
>       [ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for jakarta.enterprise:jakarta.enterprise.cdi-api:jar is 
>       missing. @ line 47, column 21
>       [ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.jboss.spec.javax.annotation:jboss-annotations- 
>       api_1.3_spec:jar is missing. @ line 55, column 21
>       [ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.jboss.spec.javax.servlet:jboss-servlet- 
>       api_4.0_spec:jar is missing. @ line 62, column 21

But in project, not declared version for any dependenci

Answer (score 0):

The site that you are trying to download belongs to accenture.
May be you are an employee at accenture.
I would suggest you to edit your settings.xml and add the maven central repo instead of accenture.

https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/

Comment: Hi guys, this error actually happened because of the version I'm using, I don't have the dependencies yet, so I changed it to 18.0.0

Answer (score 0):

this error actually happened because of the version I'm using, I don't have the dependencies yet, so I changed it to 18.0.0